# How create regex for delete all `"0"` at the beginning of string?

Tags: java, regex

How delete all `"0"` at the beginning of string?

```
00011 -> 11
00123 -> 123
000101 -> 101
101 -> 101
000002500 -> 2500
```

I tried:

```
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([1-9]{1}[0-9]?+)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("00049");
            matcher.matches();
            whatYouNeed = matcher.group();
```

I have error: `No match found`

Comment: [`0*([1-9][0-9]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/mY9qZ5/1) and replace by first capturing group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `String` only contains digits as stated in your question. You can use `String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt("00011"))`

Answer (score 3):

I'd try

```
System.out.println("Status: " + "00012010003".replaceAll("^0+", ""));
```

or regex only:

```
yourString.replaceAll("^0+", "");
```

Where

```
^ - matches only at start of string
0 - matches literal zeroes
+ - matches consecutive zeroes (at least one)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `replaceAll` with `^0*` and replace by `empty string` rather than finding a match.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use regex `(?<=^)0+` with `replaceFirst()` for this.
But parse your value to string before regex if it is in another form.

```
String val = "000011100";
String newVal = val.replaceFirst("(?<=^)0+", "");
System.out.println(newVal);
```

**Output :**

```
11100
```

Where 
`?<=^` is a look behind. The regex pattern will match only `0`'s with `^` i.e. start of string behind them.

Comment: `^` works fine by itself, you don't have to wrap it in a lookbehind.